# react-native: None of these files exist: * node_modules/@sentry/types/dist/loglevel(.native|

Tags: ios, react-native, caching, sentry

After updating a few dependencies version on my **react-native** project like **sentry** etc... when I try to build the ios bundle I am getting the error:

```
react-native: None of these files exist: * node_modules/@sentry/types/dist/loglevel(.native|......
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was clear the **react-native** cache with the command:

```
react-native start --reset-cache
```